# Insert "cut off" field in R surface plot

Tags: r, 3d, surface, rgl, geometry-surface

I'm using persp() to create a 3d plot (but I'm open to anything that will get the job done). Now I want to add a 2d field to make it clear where the 3d plot is above a specific Z value. Is there a way to achieve this? Ideally it would ideally be something like a semi transparent surface where you can see the mass under the surface vs over.

Using the example from the persp documentation

```
f <- function(x, y) { r <- sqrt(x^2+y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }

x <- seq(-10, 10, length= 30)
y <- x
z <- outer(x, y, f)
z[is.na(z)] <- 1

persp(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue",
      ltheta = 120, shade = 0.75, ticktype = "detailed",
      xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Sinc( r )"
)
```

How can I insert a field that slices the graph at a certain point of the z-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this - there are a lot more possibilities using the `rgl` package, but it has a `persp3d` function for easy upgrade from the base `graphics`.

```
library(rgl)

f <- function(x, y) { r <- sqrt(x^2+y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
x <- seq(-10, 10, length= 30)
y <- x
z <- outer(x, y, f)
z[is.na(z)] <- 1

persp3d(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue",
      ltheta = 120, shade = 0.75, ticktype = "detailed",
      xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Sinc( r )")

# Here we add a transparent purple square to mark the top

# x and y mark the corners of the purple square, z is its height
sqdf <- data.frame(x=c(-10,-10,10,10,-10),
                   y=c(-10, 10,10,-10,-10),
                   z=c(5,5,5,5,5))

# now draw the purple square, 
#    note:
#    -  the "add=T" parameter that appends it to the previous 3d-plot
#    -  the coord paramter tells it what two planes to use when 
#        tesselating the polygon into triangles 
#        (a necessary step and expensive to calculate)

polygon3d(sqdf$x,sqdf$y,sqdf$z,coord=c(1,2),alpha=0.5,color="purple",add=T)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Any feedback for this?

Comment: Sorry been travelling for the past few days - this is perfect, thank you so much.

Comment: A follow up question - I'm trying to plot p.values as I vary different parameters. My first attempt gives an "'x' and 'n' must have the same length " warning when I try to run "outer". Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?  
  
`x <- seq(10000, 100000, length=10)
y <- x  
    f <- function(x, y) { prop.test(c(rbinom(1, x, 0.5), rbinom(1, y, 0.4)), c(x, y))$p.value }
    z <- outer(x, y, f)`

Comment: The error message is coming from `prop.test` not from `outer`. It is not clear to me what you are doing though. Break it up into small steps with (i.e. calculate explicit vector inputs for the `prop.test` function) and make sure you are calculating what you want. And don't put it into the function `f` until it works, it makes sense to you, and seems to be calculating what you want.