# Adding points to persp 3D plot - hide or obscure points when behind surface

Tags: r, shiny

Background:

I'm attempting to add a 3D plot to a Shiny application. I've added a button to rotate the plot ~ 90 degrees. I'd also like to include radio buttons to plot points on the surface.

Problem:

When points are plotted they simply appear on top of the image, even when they should be behind the surface.

Question:

Is there a way to plot the surface so that it's transparent and points appear either behind or in front? Or hide the points if they land out of eyesight?

Data:

```
d <- list(x = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 
6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10), y = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 
3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10), 
    z = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000147818839413345, 0.00112553487724733, 
    0.00210325091508131, 0.00308096695291529, 0.00405868299074927, 
    0.00503639902858325, 0.00601411506641723, 0.00699183110425121, 
    0.00796954714208519, 0.00894726317991917, 0.00992497921775315, 
    0.0109026952555871, 0.0118804112934211, 0.0128581273312551, 
    0.0138358433690891, 0.0148135594069231, 0.015791275444757, 
    0.016768991482591, 0.017746707520425, 0.018724423558259, 
    0.019702139596093, 0.00332663525507192, 0.0253299512993333, 
    0.0473332673435947, 0.0693365833878561, 0.0913398994321175, 
    0.113343215476379, 0.13534653152064, 0.157349847564902, 0.179353163609163, 
    0.201356479653424, 0.223359795697686, 0.245363111741947, 
    0.267366427786209, 0.28936974383047, 0.311373059874731, 0.333376375918993, 
    0.355379691963254, 0.377383008007516, 0.399386324051777, 
    0.421389640096038, 0.4433929561403, 0.0185048854236584, 0.140901484725856, 
    0.263298084028054, 0.385694683330252, 0.50809128263245, 0.630487881934648, 
    0.752884481236846, 0.875281080539044, 0.997677679841242, 
    1.12007427914344, 1.24247087844564, 1.36486747774784, 1.48726407705003, 
    1.60966067635223, 1.73205727565443, 1.85445387495663, 1.97685047425883, 
    2.09924707356102, 2.22164367286322, 2.34404027216542, 2.46643687146762, 
    0.0575583422570596, 0.438265663185897, 0.818972984114734, 
    1.19968030504357, 1.58038762597241, 1.96109494690124, 2.34180226783008, 
    2.72250958875892, 3.10321690968776, 3.48392423061659, 3.86463155154543, 
    4.24533887247427, 4.6260461934031, 5.00675351433194, 5.38746083526078, 
    5.76816815618962, 6.14887547711845, 6.52958279804729, 6.91029011897613, 
    7.29099743990496, 7.6717047608338, 0.129117933403967, 0.98314083577592, 
    1.83716373814787, 2.69118664051983, 3.54520954289178, 4.39923244526373, 
    5.25325534763568, 6.10727825000764, 6.96130115237959, 7.81532405475154, 
    8.6693469571235, 9.52336985949545, 10.3773927618674, 11.2314156642394, 
    12.0854385666113, 12.9394614689833, 13.7934843713552, 14.6475072737272, 
    15.5015301760991, 16.3555530784711, 17.209575980843, 0.23363441995763, 
    1.77895922624881, 3.32428403254, 4.86960883883118, 6.41493364512237, 
    7.96025845141355, 9.50558325770473, 11.0509080639959, 12.5962328702871, 
    14.1415576765783, 15.6868824828695, 17.2322072891607, 18.7775320954518, 
    20.322856901743, 21.8681817080342, 23.4135065143254, 24.9588313206166, 
    26.5041561269078, 28.0494809331989, 29.5948057394901, 31.1401305457813, 
    0.36143039040365, 2.75203425835922, 5.14263812631479, 7.53324199427035, 
    9.92384586222592, 12.3144497301815, 14.7050535981371, 17.0956574660926, 
    19.4862613340482, 21.8768652020038, 24.2674690699593, 26.6580729379149, 
    29.0486768058705, 31.439280673826, 33.8298845417816, 36.2204884097372, 
    38.6110922776927, 41.0016961456483, 43.3923000136039, 45.7829038815594, 
    48.173507749515, 0.494048345421132, 3.76182525870662, 7.02960217199211, 
    10.2973790852776, 13.5651559985631, 16.8329329118486, 20.1007098251341, 
    23.3684867384196, 26.636263651705, 29.9040405649905, 33.171817478276, 
    36.4395943915615, 39.707371304847, 42.9751482181325, 46.242925131418, 
    49.5107020447035, 52.778478957989, 56.0462558712744, 59.3140327845599, 
    62.5818096978454, 65.8495866111309, 0.608277972936286, 4.63160227964344, 
    8.65492658635059, 12.6782508930577, 16.7015751997649, 20.724899506472, 
    24.7482238131792, 28.7715481198863, 32.7948724265935, 36.8181967333006, 
    40.8415210400078, 44.8648453467149, 48.8881696534221, 52.9114939601292, 
    56.9348182668364, 60.9581425735435, 64.9814668802507, 69.0047911869578, 
    73.028115493665, 77.0514398003722, 81.0747641070793, 0.68169864474794, 
    5.19064825215217, 9.6995978595564, 14.2085474669606, 18.7174970743649, 
    23.2264466817691, 27.7353962891733, 32.2443458965776, 36.7532955039818, 
    41.262245111386, 45.7711947187903, 50.2801443261945, 54.7890939335987, 
    59.298043541003, 63.8069931484072, 68.3159427558114, 72.8248923632157, 
    77.3338419706199, 81.8427915780241, 86.3517411854284, 90.8606907928326, 
    0.698331143785818, 5.31729285196915, 9.93625456015249, 14.5552162683358, 
    19.1741779765192, 23.7931396847025, 28.4121013928858, 33.0310631010692, 
    37.6500248092525, 42.2689865174358, 46.8879482256192, 51.5069099338025, 
    56.1258716419859, 60.7448333501692, 65.3637950583525, 69.9827567665359, 
    74.6017184747192, 79.2206801829025, 83.8396418910859, 88.4586035992692, 
    93.0775653074525, 0.653010606586468, 4.9722093330084, 9.29140805943032, 
    13.6106067858523, 17.9298055122742, 22.2490042386961, 26.568202965118, 
    30.88740169154, 35.2066004179619, 39.5257991443838, 43.8449978708057, 
    48.1641965972277, 52.4833953236496, 56.8025940500715, 61.1217927764935, 
    65.4409915029154, 69.7601902293373, 74.0793889557592, 78.3985876821812, 
    82.7177864086031, 87.036985135025, 0.553337675961259, 4.21327116124787, 
    7.87320464653448, 11.5331381318211, 15.1930716171077, 18.8530051023943, 
    22.5129385876809, 26.1728720729675, 29.8328055582542, 33.4927390435408, 
    37.1526725288274, 40.812606014114, 44.4725394994006, 48.1324729846872, 
    51.7924064699738, 55.4523399552604, 59.112273440547, 62.7722069258337, 
    66.4321404111203, 70.0920738964069, 73.7520073816935, 0.418509049668882, 
    3.18664747819306, 5.95478590671724, 8.72292433524142, 11.4910627637656, 
    14.2592011922898, 17.027339620814, 19.7954780493381, 22.5636164778623, 
    25.3317549063865, 28.0998933349107, 30.8680317634349, 33.636170191959, 
    36.4043086204832, 39.1724470490074, 41.9405854775316, 44.7087239060558, 
    47.4768623345799, 50.2450007631041, 53.0131391916283, 55.7812776201525, 
    0.274945103406177, 2.09351057307846, 3.91207604275075, 5.73064151242304, 
    7.54920698209532, 9.36777245176761, 11.1863379214399, 13.0049033911122, 
    14.8234688607845, 16.6420343304568, 18.460599800129, 20.2791652698013, 
    22.0977307394736, 23.9162962091459, 25.7348616788182, 27.5534271484905, 
    29.3719926181628, 31.1905580878351, 33.0091235575073, 34.8276890271796, 
    36.6462544968519, 0.14939138421548, 1.1375086826693, 2.12562598112311, 
    3.11374327957693, 4.10186057803075, 5.08997787648456, 6.07809517493838, 
    7.06621247339219, 8.05432977184601, 9.04244707029983, 10.0305643687536, 
    11.0186816672075, 12.0067989656613, 12.9949162641151, 13.9830335625689, 
    14.9711508610227, 15.9592681594765, 16.9473854579304, 17.9355027563842, 
    18.923620054838, 19.9117373532918, 0.0610345623904979, 0.464734596487648, 
    0.868434630584799, 1.27213466468195, 1.6758346987791, 2.07953473287625, 
    2.4832347669734, 2.88693480107055, 3.2906348351677, 3.69433486926485, 
    4.098034903362, 4.50173493745915, 4.9054349715563, 5.30913500565345, 
    5.7128350397506, 6.11653507384775, 6.52023510794491, 6.92393514204206, 
    7.32763517613921, 7.73133521023636, 8.13503524433351, 0.0150842607904164, 
    0.114855871447028, 0.214627482103639, 0.31439909276025, 0.414170703416861, 
    0.513942314073472, 0.613713924730083, 0.713485535386694, 
    0.813257146043305, 0.913028756699917, 1.01280036735653, 1.11257197801314, 
    1.21234358866975, 1.31211519932636, 1.41188680998297, 1.51165842063958, 
    1.61143003129619, 1.71120164195281, 1.81097325260942, 1.91074486326603, 
    2.01051647392264, 0.00112075907879118, 0.00853377984279572, 
    0.0159468006068003, 0.0233598213708048, 0.0307728421348093, 
    0.0381858628988139, 0.0455988836628184, 0.0530119044268229, 
    0.0604249251908275, 0.067837945954832, 0.0752509667188366, 
    0.0826639874828411, 0.0900770082468456, 0.0974900290108502, 
    0.104903049774855, 0.112316070538859, 0.119729091302864, 
    0.127142112066868, 0.134555132830873, 0.141968153594877, 
    0.149381174358882, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(21L, 21L)), facetcol = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
    23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 
    22L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 44L, 3L, 
    6L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 21L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 40L, 
    44L, 47L, 50L, 53L, 56L, 59L, 62L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 15L, 19L, 
    23L, 28L, 32L, 36L, 40L, 44L, 48L, 52L, 56L, 60L, 64L, 68L, 
    72L, 76L, 80L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 23L, 27L, 32L, 37L, 42L, 
    46L, 51L, 56L, 61L, 65L, 70L, 75L, 80L, 84L, 89L, 94L, 4L, 
    9L, 14L, 19L, 24L, 29L, 34L, 39L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 60L, 65L, 
    70L, 75L, 80L, 85L, 90L, 95L, 100L, 4L, 9L, 14L, 19L, 24L, 
    29L, 34L, 39L, 44L, 49L, 54L, 59L, 64L, 69L, 74L, 78L, 83L, 
    88L, 93L, 98L, 3L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 21L, 26L, 30L, 35L, 39L, 
    43L, 48L, 52L, 57L, 61L, 66L, 70L, 75L, 79L, 83L, 88L, 3L, 
    6L, 10L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 28L, 32L, 35L, 39L, 42L, 46L, 
    49L, 53L, 57L, 60L, 64L, 67L, 71L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 
    15L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 25L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 43L, 
    46L, 48L, 51L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 
    17L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("(-0.357,3.59]", "(3.59,7.18]", 
    "(7.18,10.8]", "(10.8,14.4]", "(14.4,17.9]", "(17.9,21.5]", 
    "(21.5,25.1]", "(25.1,28.7]", "(28.7,32.3]", "(32.3,35.9]", 
    "(35.9,39.5]", "(39.5,43.1]", "(43.1,46.6]", "(46.6,50.2]", 
    "(50.2,53.8]", "(53.8,57.4]", "(57.4,61]", "(61,64.6]", "(64.6,68.2]", 
    "(68.2,71.8]", "(71.8,75.3]", "(75.3,78.9]", "(78.9,82.5]", 
    "(82.5,86.1]", "(86.1,89.7]", "(89.7,93.3]", "(93.3,96.9]", 
    "(96.9,100]", "(100,104]", "(104,108]", "(108,111]", "(111,115]", 
    "(115,118]", "(118,122]", "(122,126]", "(126,129]", "(129,133]", 
    "(133,136]", "(136,140]", "(140,144]", "(144,147]", "(147,151]", 
    "(151,154]", "(154,158]", "(158,161]", "(161,165]", "(165,169]", 
    "(169,172]", "(172,176]", "(176,179]", "(179,183]", "(183,187]", 
    "(187,190]", "(190,194]", "(194,197]", "(197,201]", "(201,204]", 
    "(204,208]", "(208,212]", "(212,215]", "(215,219]", "(219,222]", 
    "(222,226]", "(226,230]", "(230,233]", "(233,237]", "(237,240]", 
    "(240,244]", "(244,248]", "(248,251]", "(251,255]", "(255,258]", 
    "(258,262]", "(262,265]", "(265,269]", "(269,273]", "(273,276]", 
    "(276,280]", "(280,283]", "(283,287]", "(287,291]", "(291,294]", 
    "(294,298]", "(298,301]", "(301,305]", "(305,309]", "(309,312]", 
    "(312,316]", "(316,319]", "(319,323]", "(323,326]", "(326,330]", 
    "(330,334]", "(334,337]", "(337,341]", "(341,344]", "(344,348]", 
    "(348,352]", "(352,355]", "(355,359]"), class = "factor"))
```

Code

```
flip <- 1 # 1 or 2
theta = c(-300,120)[flip]
pmat <- persp(d$x, d$y, d$z, asp = 1,col = color[d$facetcol], phi = 30, theta = theta, border = "grey10"
              ,d = .8,r = 2.8,expand = .6,shade = .2,axes = F,box = T,cex = .1)
xx <- c(7.76245335753423, 6.73123147037805)
yy <- c(4.88402435072353, 4.20867046100364)
zz <- c(68.727, 48.558)
mypoints <- trans3d(xx,yy,zz,pmat = pmat)
points(mypoints,pch = 16,col = 2)
```

The image below is correct, but when the plot is rotated (set `flip` to 2) the points do not jive. In other words, when the plot is rotated the points should be hidden from view, or seen through a semi-transparent surface. Help is appreciated!

[image: Correct]

Comment: `persp` is an ink on paper plotting functions, so if the points are added after the surface is created they will always be visible. You need rgl for true (or at least much better) 3d effects.

Comment: Here's an example (in the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043991/insert-cut-off-field-in-r-surface-plot I also checked SO via searching on : `[r] shiny rgl` to make sure that those two paradigms were compatible.

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM ! I'll give it a whirl today. I appreciate the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case this is helpful to anyone. I ended up using the `persp3D()` function from the `plot3D` package. All my custom axes labels and tick marks transferred seamlessly from the base `persp()` with the added bonus of a transparency argument (`alpha =`) and proper point plotting (`points3D`).

[image]